# Set default password management for users in puppet

Tags: linux, bash, puppet

When declaring a new user creation in Puppet, how can you set the default password management type and encryption?

- How can I set one user to be managed independently?
- How can I set one to be managed by puppet exclusively?

**Independent:** Do I just place a deceleration to /etc/passwd, e.g:

```
user{ "foo":
    ensure => present,
    managehome => true,
    home =>"/home/foo",
    password => "/etc/passwd",
    uid => "001"
}
```

I read an example in puppetforge [example](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/accounts)

```
accounts::user { 'bob':
uid      => 4001,
gid      => 4001,
shell    => '/bin/bash',
password => '!!',
}
```

I keep seeing `password => !!` But I cannot seem to find documentation for `password => !!` [example](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/quick_start_user_group.html)

**SSH managed:** Then when it comes to managing directly with SSH Puppet, I just map it to the key? e.g. (from puppetforge)

```
accounts::user { 'jeff':
  comment => 'Jeff McCune',
  groups  => [
    'admin',
    'sudonopw',
  ],
  uid     => '1112',
  gid     => '1112',
  sshkeys => [
    'ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...== jeff@puppetlabs.com',
    'ssh-dss AAAAB3Nza...== jeff@metamachine.net',
  ],
}
```

Where I assume the above RSA `AAAAB3Nza...` is a generated (externally, copied) and then stored in hard-code? The user can then auth using `jeff@puppetlabs.com` which is mapped to the RSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In puppet, if you don't specify the password, it won't manage the password.  If you specify a password, it ensures that value is placed in /etc/shadow.  That value really should be an encrypted value.  The double exclamation mark is the "not a password" value, and the account is then unable to be authenticated with a password.